# how to create dynamic sql php calendar?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, dynamic, calendar

I have created a bootstrap calendar and I want to retrieve  the event from the sql database but it is not working

I stored the `start_date` and `end_date` in the calendar with `datetime` data type

I followed some tutorial and write this piece of  php code:

```
<?php
include_once ("dbconnection.php");

//load.php
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM Event ORDER BY event_id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row[.'event_id'.],
  'title'   => $row[.'Title'.],
  'start'   => $row[.'start_date'.],
  'end'   => $row[.'end_date'.]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

after i run the code there is no event in the calendar

Comment: You should start using some kind of IDE which would highlight syntax errors for you. VS code is a good cheap option.

Comment: **$row[.'event_id'.]** should be **$row['event_id']**. No dots - it's not string concatenation. This is true for the other three key-value pairs in the $data array. Then **$data[] = array()** should be **$data = array()**. No need for square brackets - that's something else. (That says: the new element in the $data array is an array, so you'll have only one element in your $data array.)

Comment: i've changed it and nothing has changed

Comment: Pls, go step by step - check every line if it works, and locate the first one that doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

array_push($data,['id' => $row['event_id'], 'title' => $row['Title'], 'start' => $row['start_date'], 'end' => $row['end_date']]);